# Problema com API da Poloniex

Tags: python, api

Estou tendo problemas com a API da Poloniex, quando executo o código

```
polo = poloniex.Poloniex('key', 'secret')
polo.sell('BTC_MoedaX', 0.003, 3)
polo.buy('BTC_MoedaX', 0.003, 3)
```

Retorna o erro:

```
{'error': 'Amount must be at least 0.000001.'}
```

Porém o montante indicado no terceiro parâmetro é maior que 0.000001 e mesmo assim retorna este erro.

Edit: 
Documentação da API: https://poloniex.com/support/api/
Código que estou utilizando: https://pastebin.com/fbkheaRb (o mesmo disponível na documentação, porém ao invés de urllib utilizo o request.

Comment: Já tentou `('BTC_MoedaX', 0.003, (0.01*0.003))` ?

Comment: Já, da o mesmo erro

Comment: Para alguém poder responder sua pergunta, a pessoa teria que ou ter mais contexto, ou usar tambéma api da poloniex - -ela tem muito poiuco susuários, relativamente a quem sabe responder perguntas aqui (eu mesmo não tenho registro lá, por que nunca liberaram minha conta).

Comment: então você precisa dar mais informações: Você consegue sucesso com outras chamadas a API? Pode por exemplos de chamadas que funcionam? Tem outras APIś numéricas? Tem um link para a documentação desses métodos "buy" e "sell" aí? - do jeito que está não sabemos o que é cada parâmetro. 

E por fim - funciona colocar números direto na API, ou você deveria estar mandando os números como strings?

Comment: Editei o post com as informações pedidas